# bootstrap buttons with icon label issues when it's a block button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm trying to use [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-with-labels) addition to bootstrap buttons.  which adds a nifty "label" for the icons at the beginning of the button.  but the problem lies when it's a "btn-block" type.

```
.btn-label {position: relative;left: -12px;display: inline-block;padding: 6px 12px;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;}
.btn-labeled {padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;}
```

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0keueno/) I figure it's the

```
left:-12px;
```

as the position but how would I determine what negative number it would be if it's block?  ideas?

Comment: Here is a better fiddle that is easier to read.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/g0keueno/1/

Comment: Give `text-align:left` to the button. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g0keueno/2/)

Comment: @anpsmn that did it! wanna put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Andres Cool. Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `text-align:left` to the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-labeled btn-block btn-custom">
    <span class="btn-label">here</span>
    problem
</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-labeled">
    <span class="btn-label">no</span>
    problem
</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn-custom { text-align: left;}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g0keueno/2/)